# jQuery Select2 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I implemented the search from the list of options via Ajax and is working perfectly. However, to fill other cascading selects, I would save some html5 "data" attributes on populated options. The method "results" only expects an array with the ids and texts. Any idea?

```
    results: function(data, page) {
      return { results: $.map(data, function(city, i) {
        return {id: city.id, text: city.name};
        // I tried adding data- attributes to return but didn't work
      })}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **formatResult**. http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/4098/

```
$("#e4").select2({
    formatResult: function(state) {
        return '<div data-my="' + ... + '">' + state.text + '</div>';
    },
    ...
});
```